# Make textarea readonly with jquery

Tags: jquery

For text `input` I do:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
});
```

But what should I do for `textarea`, to make it `readonly`.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Include it in your selector (using a [multiple](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)/[element](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) selector), like this:

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').attr('readonly','readonly');
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JkyH8/), if it's the *only* thing you're doing, there's no need for a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), you can just call [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) on all matched elements.

Answer (score 21):

In latest versions of jQuery, the use of method `prop` is preferred over use of `attr`.

To make a particular textarea readonly:
`$('#mytextarea1').prop('readonly', true);`

To make all textareas readonly:
`$('textarea').prop('readonly', true);`

To make all 'text' fields readonly:
`$('input[type=text]').prop('readonly', true);`

To make all 'text' fields and textarea readonly:
`$('input[type=text],textarea').prop('readonly', true);`

Please also note the difference between 'readonly' and 'disabled' in terms of appearance:

Below is a `<textarea>` with `disabled` set to `true`:
[image: Textarea disabled](looks different from a regular textarea)

Below is a `<textarea>` with `readonly` set to `true`:
[image: textarea readonly](looks same as a regular textarea)

Answer (score 13):

From Jquery 1.6 use

```
$("#mytxtarea").prop("disabled", true);
```

Visit http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: me tried this.
but the text area not enables again if I reload the page.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
$("#mytxtarea").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
$("textarea").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

this will make readonly to all textarea fields.

Comment: disabled isn't readonly + you actually mixed answers that have been here for few years.

Comment: Yes! you are true. Now i make change on my answer. Thank you for comment.