# How to create a non-editable type(like tags) when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I got several buttons created in a loop dynamically.

```
<input class="btn btn-info attribute-button" name="commit" type="button" value="first_name">
```

And i got a text field.

```
<textarea class="text optional special form-control" data-role="tagsinput" id="campaign_message" maxlength="180" name="campaign[message]"></textarea>
```

these are created by my rails application.

and this is my js code to add the value of the button into the text field

```
  $(document).on("click",".attribute-button", function(){

      var value = $('.special').val($('.special').val() + $(this).val());})
```

what i want to do is this;

when a button is pressed i can already write the content on the text are but what i want is to write them as non-editable texts.User shouldn't be able to modify the added text.

http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap-2.3.2.html

i found this lib but it didn't work out for me since it doesn't support a text are.He apply tags to all inputs.But i will have tags and input texts together.

how can i achieve this?

Comment: simply don't use a `<textarea>` if you don't want user interaction. use a `<span>` or a `<div>` and a hidden input.

Comment: @Pointy i need a text area textfield is simply too little for me.How can i create <div> or <span> each time my js code added that input to the text area?

Comment: A single `<input type=text>` can hold as much text as a `<textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the awnser of this question. All you have to do is make the field readonly if you do not want people to add text.

[Make textarea readonly with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297923/make-textarea-readonly-with-jquery)

You can do this with a button click event

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. There is a div with the class of tags. Inside it are divs with the class of tag and a text field with the class of newtag. When you enter text into newtag and hit space, enter or tab, a new tag div will be inserted. If you click a button with the class of attribute-button, its value will be added to a tag div. You will need to add thing to complete it such as a delete button on the tags to remove it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xpoeth6/)

HTML:

```
<input class="btn btn-info attribute-button" name="commit" type="button" value="first_name" />
<div class="tags">
    <input type="text" name="newtag" class="newtag" placeholder="Add tags" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".tags, .attribute-button").click(function(){
    $(".newtag").focus();
})
$(".newtag").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13 || e.which === 32 || e.which === 9){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".newtag").before("<div class='tag'>"+$(".newtag").val()+"</div>");
        $(".newtag").val("");
    }
});
$(".attribute-button").click(function(){
    $(".newtag").before("<div class='tag'>"+$(this).val()+"</div>");
})
```

CSS (optional):

```
.tags{
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px;
}
.tag{
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.newtag{
    border: none;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: your code looks good except one thing, it make the normal inputs as tag aswell.I don't want that to happen.Can you fix it?I can create a remove button but normal inputs shouldn't be tags

Comment: @railsnewbie Yeah, you just have to remove the block that starts with $(".newtag").keydown(function(e){. Here is a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6xpoeth6/1/

Comment: sorry for bothering but i can't seem to understand your code, can you just do a little bit of fix once more and i want the firstname tag wherever the last point where, i mean User should be able to enter "hello dear first name, how are you?" But your code applies "firstname hello dear, how are you?"

Comment: I do not understand the question. Don't worry about bothering me, I'm bored.

Comment: Well as i explained in the comment.When i click on the "firstname" it just create another uneditable div AT THE START of the text field.What i want is to put a firstname uneditable div where ever it was.

Comment: @railsnewbie You want it to place the new div where the cursor is? That is not possible, input textfields cannot contain divs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59949/discussion-between-railsnewbie-and-marcel).